# How to wait forever until an event is raised?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I'm pretty sure that this has a relatively easy answer, but somehow I cannot find it.

In examples of console applications that handle events (e.g. https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html but I've seen many others as well) I see code like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
        var someObject = new MyClassWithEvents();
        someObject.SomeEventFired += () =>
        {
            // do whatever
        };

        Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Now the obvious problem with this is that if you go beyond example code (where you can wait for a key to be pressed) and remove the `Console.ReadLine()` the thread exits (or if you're not in `Main()`, you go out of context) and the events are no longer processed.

I guess I could use an eternal `while(true) { Sleep() }` but wouldn't that also block the thread from receiving the events?

What would be the correct way of writing this kind of program? The idea is that it looks much like a service, waiting there doing nothing until an event is fired.

To see what I mean, try the following code:

```
public static void Main() 
{ 
  var someObject = new MyClassWithEvents();
  someObject.SomeEventFired += () => 
  {
     // do whatever
  }; 
}
```

This exits immediately!

TIA,

Jim

Comment: A spin-wait is the last thing you want. But let's assume you found a means to "wait forever" without `Console.ReadLine()`. How is your program supposed to terminate? Never? Then a service might exactly be what you actually want?

Comment: Thanks for the answer :-) I simplfied for the sake of brevity, but usually there is some trigger that tells the program to exit. A file has been created, a message is received with a specific content, whatever.

But until the "trigger" happens, it should wait.

Comment: The method you are calling which eventually will fire the event is async? If not I don't see why you need to wait anyway because you are calling it synchronously so you are already blocking, if it is async don't you want to await the async task?

Comment: Then this might be of your interest: [ManualResetEventSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @RandRandom it's not (it's sync) but to see what I mean, try the following code:

```
public static void Main()
{
        var someObject = new MyClassWithEvents();
        someObject.SomeEventFired += () =>
        {
            // do whatever
        };

        Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This exists immediately!

Comment: This is what I mean - https://dotnetfiddle.net/AG4UBm

Comment: Right @RandRandom, thanks, that's what mean, won't this exit immediately? What if the first event comes after a couple of minutes?

Comment: As long as the method is sync, no. It can't just randomly exit the program the method `Foo` - in my example - has to finish before going to the next line, so it will block as long as `Foo` is running, and since the event registration is before calling `Foo` you will get the event that is called inside `Foo`.

Comment: @RandRandom There is no "Foo" in OP's case. Imagine he's setting up a FileSystemWatcher to get notified of new files in a directory, that shall be processed in some way. He'd setup the watcher and then have to _wait_ for something to happen.

Comment: @Fildor - I guess you meant to say there is "no" or? If that's the case, I know I just assumed that there has to be a method involved that will eventually fire the event. In my case `Foo` will fire the event `SomeEventFired`, I wouldn't know how else an event would fire. It seems to be OPs custom class, and OPs custom event, so OP is calling the event somewhere, and where else if not from a method?

Comment: @RandRandom yes, I meant "there is no" ... thanks. Well, from where else ... a high probability is on external I/O. As mentioned: a FileSystemWatcher, maybe Network I/O, Serial I/O ... anything that works event-based.

Comment: Right guys, exactly, my concrete example these days is rabbitmq queues, but FileSystemWatcher is an excellent example as well.

Comment: Yeah, that of course is a different story. @Fildor 's crystal ball was more accurate than mine. :)

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this, but I'd try this as the simplest approach:

```
public static ManualResetEventSlim waiter = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
public static void Main()
{
        var someObject = new MyClassWithEvents();
        someObject.SomeEventFired += () =>
        {
            // do whatever
        };
        
        // Just an example for an "Exit-Trigger"
        someObject.ExitProgramEventFired += () =>
        {
            waiter.Set(); // Signal the MRE to stop blocking.
        };

        waiter.Wait(); // Blocks until signalled.
        Console.WriteLine("Exit Program has been triggered.");

        // Cleanup resources ...
    }
}
```

Mind: The `Wait` method also comes with overloads to support cancellation and timeout, so you can really harden your design.

For reference: [ManualResetEventSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a newer version of .Net, you can make your entry point a `Task Main` instead of `void Main`. Then you can use a `TaskCompletionSource` to return a task that will finish when the cancel key is pressed.

Doing it this way should free up the main thread back into the Thread pool, which means it should use less resources.

```
public static Task Main(string[] args)
{
    // Set up TaskCompletionSource that completes when the CancelKey is Pressed
    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    Console.CancelKeyPress += (_, args) =>
    {
        args.Cancel = true;
        taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(true);
    };

    var someObject = new MyClassWithEvents();
    someObject.SomeEventFired += () => 
    {
        // do whatever
    };

    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

Should mention though, you asked '*wouldn't that also block the thread from receiving the events*', but that shouldn't be an issue. Callbacks usually don't come back on the main thread, they are usually handled by a random free thread from the thread pool. So even if the main thread is blocked by something, callbacks like that will usually still run.

Comment: Does this just wrap an event handler into a Task or what is the purpose?

Comment: @user3625699 Yep this just returns a task to Main() that will never finish unless the application is asked to close. The main thing is that the task being returned to Main does not finish AND does not use a thread doing nothing.